# Hive query for finding table name which contain a particular column

Tags: sql, sql-server, hive, hue

I have written following query in SQL Server to view Table and column names

```
select * from information_schema.COLUMNS where column_name like '%name%'
```

Is there any similar query which can be written in **Hive** for similar result?
If not then how can I find list of tables in a particular Database which contains a particular column?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any option available in Hive. You can use shell scripting to get the same output. Something like this:

```
output=""
hive -S -e 'show databases' | while read database
do
   eval "hive -S -e 'show tables in $database'" | while read line
   do
     if eval "hive -S -e 'describe $database.$line'" | grep -q "<column_name"; then
          eval "hive -S -e 'show columns in $database.$line'" | while read column
          do
             output="$output$database.$line,$column"'\n'
          done
     fi
   done
done
echo -e "$output"
```

Comment: Thanks for response @Naveen. I tried below code......
hive -S -e 'show databases' | while read database
 do eval "hive -S -e 'show tables in $database'" | while read line
  do if eval "hive -S -e 'describe $database.$line'"| grep -q "name";
   then output="Required table name: $database.$line"'\n';
    else output=""'\n'; 
   fi echo -e "$output"
  done 
 done
.......
But the problem is it is giving result one by one(in a loop) and I want a complete list of tables. Also I want the exact name of column to be printed along with column name, so how can I get that?

Comment: For list of tables: You can append the output variable for each loop and then print or write it to a file after exiting the loop(while read database).

Comment: And do you want to print list of all the columns of each table (where column name is matching) or only the specified column name which you are searching for?

Comment: I want all the columns of each table where the part of column name is matching.

Comment: i have updated the answer. You can use "show columns in table_name".